# There's a way to capture the push notification in ios?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cordova

There's a way to capture the push notification in Ios? In order to receive a notification from an external app (for example an asp.net app) with some content and not display the push notification to the user  and get the useful content?

If you also know of a way to do this in phonegap, it's useful to me as well.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the app is in background or not running you can't capture the push notification.

Otherwise if the app is in foreground the method **application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:** of the AppDelegate will be called when the app receives a push notification and then you can do whatever you want with the information in the Push Notification.

> Let’s review the possible scenarios when the system delivers a local notification or a remote notification for an application.
>
> The notification is delivered when **the application isn’t running in the foreground**.
>   In this case, the system presents the notification, displaying an alert, badging an icon, perhaps playing a sound.
>
> As a result of the presented notification, the user taps the action button of the alert or taps (or clicks) the application icon.
>   If the action button is tapped (on a device running iOS), the system launches the application and the application calls its delegate’s application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method (if implemented); it passes in the notification payload (for remote notifications) or the local-notification object (for local notifications).
>
> If the application icon is tapped on a device running iOS, the application calls the same method, but furnishes no information about the notification . If the application icon is clicked on a computer running OS X, the application calls the delegate’s applicationDidFinishLaunching: method in which the delegate can obtain the remote-notification payload.
>
> The notification is delivered when **the application is running in the foreground**.
>   The application calls its delegate’s **application:didReceiveRemoteNotification: method** (for remote notifications) or application:didReceiveLocalNotification: method (for local notifications) and passes in the notification payload or the local-notification object.

Please see the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction.html) for more information.